# Is there any app that would change my desktop bg automatically every day, like with the picture of the day?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

What I want is an app that changes automatically with every days picture, like Wallch or Variety, except these 2 doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: Whats your ubuntu or gnome-shell version

Comment: Variety works fine in all systems I'm using it.

Comment: My gnome-shell version is 3.36.9.

Comment: If you find applications that don't work, then please do a bit of troubleshooting. Periodically-changing wallpapers work fine for lots of people. If you're not sure how to troubleshoot, open a new question and ask....

Comment: Have you tried using shotwell as described in [this article](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/4-wallpaper-changer-ubuntu-18-04/)?

Comment: Sometimes a (scheduled) simple script may do the work.

Comment: Here's another script that I use on my system: https://github.com/muru/scripts/blob/master/fav-wallpapers (started at login using a systemd user service)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a script to randomly choose a wallpaper and then you can set that script to run when you log in.

**First**, create a directory named `~/wallpaper` containing only your background or wallpaper images.

**Then**, run the following command to create the file you need to run a wallpaper script.

```
install -D /dev/null ~/bin/wallpapernew
```

Log out and then log back in.

**Next**, use your favorite text editor to edit your `~/bin/wallpapernew` file.

Copy and paste the following into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$HOME/wallpaper
PIC="$(find $DIR | shuf -n1)"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$PIC"
```

Save the file and exit your text editor.

**Then**, open the application "Startup Applications" and click <kbd>Add</kbd>.

In the "Name" field type `wallpaper`

In the "Command" field type `wallpapernew`

In the "Comment" field type `script to change wallpaper`

[image]

**Finally,** click <kbd>Add</kbd> and close the Startup Applications application.

Log out and log back in to change your wallpaper.

Comment: To test this command, just run the command `wallpapernew` in the terminal and it should change your wallpaper to a random image from your `~/wallpaper directory`.

Comment: I am curious. Why use the `sed` to globally replace `HOME` with `$HOME` after editing the file, rather than type `$HOME` in the file while editing the file in the first place?

Comment: @user68186 This will replace `HOME` with the variable of what `HOME` is equal to e.g., `echo $HOME`  . I wasn't sure if environment variables were defined in crontab so I decided to use a static path. When you want to pass a path variable to `sed`, the trick is to use double quotation marks and pipe symbols instead of single quotes and forward slashes.

Comment: I got it now. I would just write `DIR=$HOME/wallpaper` in the bash script and skip the step with `sed`.

Comment: @user68186 Okay so I checked and $HOME does get passed on to cron but gsettings doesn't work so I switched to Startup Applications and used $HOME in the script.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks but [it's a bit more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374520/gsettings-with-cron). I decided to go with the startup program to keep it simple. Although, `$HOME` did work (I tried it with `echo`) so now I know that for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

`variety`, available in the standard Ubuntu software repositories, is an application that does that.